# How to expand storage in Single node Elasticsearch

Tags: linux, storage, centos, elasticsearch

We need to increase storage capacity for `Elasticsearch` working on a **Single CentOS node**. Even if Elasticsearch support multiple path I don't think it's useful and they also suggest not to use it. Other two options they suggesting is either add one more node or use Linux's `Logical Volume Manager(LVM)`. I wanted to know how the latter option works for ES, since I am newbie to both Linux file system and Elasticsearch itself I found quite hard to understand the things.

Our current data path for ES is default `/var/lib/elasticseach/data`

If I add one more disk to this VM how can I make use of it using `LVM` without the need of migration or long down time. We'd already disabled replica shards as it is a single node.

Additionally is it possible to make use of `Index lifecycle policies` and it's **phases(hot,warm,cold)** to move data to different disk in a single node setup?